# R extract latent factors from ALS implementation in Sparklyr

Tags: r, sparklyr, matrix-factorization

using the ALS example from the sparklyr documentation:

```
library(sparklyr)
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")

movies <- data.frame(
  user   = c(1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0),
  item   = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0),
  rating = c(3, 1, 2, 4, 5, 4)
)
movies_tbl <- sdf_copy_to(sc, movies)

model <- ml_als(movies_tbl, rating ~ user + item)
```

How can you then extract the resulting latent user and item factors from the model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got there in the end with `tidy(model)`.

Here's an updated example with 3 users and 4 items:

```
library(sparklyr)
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")

# 3 users, 4 films:
movies <- data.frame(
  user   = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3),
  item   = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4),
  rating = c(3, 1, 2, 5, 1, 5, 1, 1, 5, 4)
)
movies_tbl <- sdf_copy_to(sc, movies, overwrite = TRUE)
movies_tbl <- sdf_copy_to(sc, movies)

model <- ml_als(movies_tbl, rating ~ user + item)
```

You can extract the users and items latent factors with:

```
model_tidy <- tidy(model) %>% collect

# A tibble: 4 x 3
     id user_factors item_factors
  <int> <list>       <list>      
1     1 <list [10]>  <list [10]> 
2     3 <list [10]>  <list [10]> 
3     2 <list [10]>  <list [10]> 
4     4 <lgl [1]>    <list [10]>
```

so the list element is `<lgl[1}>` for ids that don't exist in either the user or item list.